# JavaScript convert number to date to compare against current date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Hi i have been working on the final question for my assignment and i have to check if today's date is greater than a date that is store as a number in a database. ie today's date would be 16122017 dd mm yy as you can see it has no spaces or a "-" or "/" just a number.  i can get todays date reverse it and remove the - but a simple < or > does not work for comparison as they are numbers not java date formats.

So i figure i have to add the - back into the date and reverse it so it yy mm dd and then compare it to the current date.

Can any one show me how to add - into the number format, i can simply reverse it back to yy mm dd from dd mm yy once done with

```
> c = c.split('-').reverse().join('');
```

where c is the var containing the number date. i assume once it has - back in it i could just do

> if (c > LocalDate.now())
>   or do i need to assign it to a new date var ?

Comment: no need to reverse it back if you assign to different variable

Comment: You can parse it like: `var b = '16122017'.match(/(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d{4})/); new Date(b[3],b[2]-1,b[1])`. Don't be tempted to parse it to another string that then uses the built-in parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some cool addon packages like `moment.js` that can do this with an elegant call. But, in native javascript you can do this sort of thing, using the [handy-dandy setFullYear(y,m,d) function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear).

```
var ds = '16122017'
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setFullYear(ds.substring(4,8),ds.substring(2,4)-1,ds.substring(0,2));
var today = new Date();
today.setHours (0,0,0,0); /* turn now into today */
if (myDate < today) {
   /* myDate was before today */
}
```

Comment: Just a note it works perfectly but the substring pointers where one short. myDate.setFullYear(ds.substring(4,8),ds.substring(2,4)-1,ds.substring(0,2));

Answer (score 0):

Besides using a library that can convert the dates for you, I suggest the good old substring method if you know for sure that the first two numbers are the day, then month, then year, such that

```
var day = str.substring(1, 2);
```

and so on. Then you create a new Date object based on your calculations and work with it.

If your input doesn't have trailing zeros, that adds complexity to the problem, but nothing that you can't overcome.